# Plone 4.2.4 Buildout fails with plone.app.jquery pinned to 1.4.4

Tags: plone, buildout, ploneformgen

I am having a sudden issue with installing Plone 4.2.4.  I have pinned PloneFormGen to 1.7.11 but the buildout fails with the following error:

The version, 1.4.4, is not consistent with the requirement, 'plone.app.jquery>1.6'.
While:
  Installing client1.
Error: Bad version 1.4.4

If I remove PFG from the buildout, it runs fine.  I have pinned plone.app.jquery to 1.7.2 (even though it states its not compatible with < Plone 4.3) and the buildout runs successfully, but afterwards, if I update PloneFormGen from 1.7.6 to 1.7.11, it breaks the site.

The buildout is a standard Unified Installer build of Plone 4.2.4, using the out of the box version.cfg.  I have extended this with my own config to add other components.

This build recipe I created months ago and it has worked flawlessly on other systems, but my most recent use of this recipe gives me the failures.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I found an email on the Plone Users group by someone who was having a very similar issue to this.  The fix seems to be to pin plone.app.jquery to 1.7.2 as well as pinning collective.js.jqueryui to 1.9.2.0.  I did this and the issues I was experiencing appear to be resolved.  However, I'm not comfortable with this solution as it appears to be an underlying issue with these two packages.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question update, you need to additionally pin plone.app.jquery to a newer version.

This is a fine solution and, if anything, PloneFormGen is just lacking in documentation so people are aware of it.

Please consider contributing to the README to help provide better instructions to install on the version of plone you're using: https://github.com/collective/Products.PloneFormGen/blob/master/Products/PloneFormGen/README.txt